# VueJs - class including constants and dynamic values

Tags: css, data-binding, vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to add a constant and a dynamic class to an element in Vue:

```
<div :class="button {'button-danger':danger}">Button</div>
```

Class "button" should always be applied, "button-danger" only when property 'danger' is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple as this.

```
<div class="button" :class="{'button-danger':danger}">Button</div>
```

Or

```
<div :class="{button: true, 'button-danger':danger}">Button</div>
```

```js
console.clear()

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    danger: true
  }
})
```

```css
.button-danger {
  color: red
}
.button {
 border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="button" :class="{'button-danger':danger}">Button</div>
  <div :class="{button: true, 'button-danger':danger}">Second Button</div>
  <button @click="danger = !danger">Toggle</button>
</div>
```